# Simulating a remote website locally for testing

Tags: http, web, browser-extension

I am developing a browser extension. The extension works on external websites we have no control over.

I would like to be able to test the extension. One of the major problems I'm facing is displaying a website 'as-is' locally.

Is it possible to display a website 'as-is' locally?

I want to be able to serve the website *exactly*  as-is locally for testing. This means I want to simulate the exact same HTTP data, including iframe ads, etc.

- Is there an easy way to do this?

**More info:**

I'd like my system to act as closely to the remote website as possible. I'd like to run command `fetch` for example which would allow me to go to the site in my browser (without the internet on) and get the exact same thing I would otherwise (including information that is not from a single domain, google ads, etc).

I don't mind using a virtual machine if this helps.

I figured this was quite a useful thing in testing. Especially when I have a bug I need to reliably reproduce in sites that have many random factors (what ads show, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was already mentioned, caching proxies should do the trick for you (BTW, this is the simplest solution). There are quite a lot of different implementations, so you just need to spend some time selecting a proper one (according to my experience squid is a good solution). Anyway, I would like to highlight two other interesting options:

**Option 1: [Betamax](http://freeside.co/betamax/)**

> Betamax is a tool for mocking external HTTP resources such as web services and REST APIs in your tests. The project was inspired by the VCR library for Ruby. Betamax aims to solve these problems by intercepting HTTP connections initiated by your application and replaying previously recorded responses.
>
> Betamax comes in two flavors. The first is an HTTP and HTTPS proxy that can intercept traffic made in any way that respects Java’s http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort system properties. The second is a simple wrapper for Apache HttpClient.

BTW, Betamax has a very interesting feature for you:

> Betamax is a testing tool and not a spec-compliant HTTP proxy. It ignores any and all headers that would normally be used to prevent a proxy caching or storing HTTP traffic.

**Option 2: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and replay proxy**

Grab all traffic you are interested in using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and replay it. This I would say it is not that hard to implement required replaying tool, but you can use available solution called [replayproxy](https://code.google.com/p/replayproxy/)

> Replayproxy parses HTTP streams from .pcap files
> opens a TCP socket on port 3128 and listens as a HTTP proxy using the extracted HTTP responses as a cache while refusing all requests for unknown URLs.

Such approach provide you with the full control and bit-to-bit precise simulation.

Comment: Replayproxy sounds exactly like what I need, and it's just 200 lines of code. I'm sure I'll be able to work with its code and wire-shark to get the behavior I need. This solves my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an *easy* way, but there is a way.

You can set up a local webserver, something like IIS, Apache, or [minihttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/mini_httpd/).

Then you can grab the website contents using [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). (It has an option for mirroring). And many browsers have an option for "save whole web page" that will grab everything, like images.

Ads will most likely come from remote sites, so you may have to manually edit those lines in the HTML to either not reference the actual ad-servers, or set up a mock ad yourself (like a banner image).

Then you can navigate your browser to `http://localhost` to visit your local website, assuming port 80 which is the default.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I really need to get those ads on my computer though. I'd like the test environment to be as close to the real one as possible.

Comment: In theory you can mirror the ads the same as the main website, though at some point you are probably going to run in to the fact that many ads/sites are served dynamically, not just via static content.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to serve a remote site that's not under your control. In that case you can use a proxy server and have that server cache every response aggressively. However, this has it's limits. First of all you will have to visit every site you intend to use through this proxy (with a browser for example), second you will not be able to emulate form processing.

Alternatively you could use a spider to download all content of a certain website. Depending on the spider software, it may even be able to download JavaScript-built links. You then can use a webserver to serve that content.

Comment: A proxy server sounds like a right _idea_ but how would I go on _implementing_ this sort of thing without having to write a proxy server myself?

Comment: I don't know which proxy can do that kind of aggressive caching, but you might want to take a look at squid, it's fairly popular. What OS are you using?

Comment: OS is not an issue, I don't mind using Windows or Linux for this. We're a well funded company.

Comment: OK, I *think* you can do this with squid. If I'm correct, you will need to use the reply_header_access, *_ttl and the minimum_expiry_time directives, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

This service http://www.json-gen.com provides mock for html, json and xml via rest. By this way, you can test your frontend separately from backend.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes, resulting in your answer being useless and consequently deleted.