# nodejs/mocha/nock - mocking an entire html response

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocking, mocha.js

How can I mock an entire HTML body response for my tests?

I'm using nodejs/mocha/nock.

With nock I can mock JSON responds just fine, for example:

```
nock('http://myapp.iriscouch.com')
                .get('/users/1')
                .reply(200, {_id: "123ABC", _rev: "946B7D1C", username: 'pgte'});
```

I used `curl -o` to fetch the html I want for the mock, so I have it already in a file - but I don't see how can I pass an HTML file to nock (or something else).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First fetch the HTML content of your test file and put it in a string (using `fs.readFile` for example)

after that you can do:

```
nock('http://myapp.iriscouch.com').
        get('/users/1').
        reply(200, yourFileContent);
```

This is what worked out for me in the past :)

If you'd like, you can specify the content type explicitly, since you specify the body as a string this will effectively let you mock any non-binary response easily:

```
nock('http://myapp.iriscouch.com').
        get('/users/1').
        reply(200, yourFileContent, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
```

If you want a more general approach, I've asked [a more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381927/simulating-a-remote-website-locally-for-testing) about a similar issue and got some interesting responses.